# How do you prompt a user for an input in java

Tags: java, variables, import, int, java.util.scanner

So I just started learning Java, its literally like my 1st day and I wanted to try to make a coinflip game. I already know a decent amount of Javascript and so i was trying to apply that knowledge to java. So everything has been working so far except one thing: Prompting a user for a choice. So read online that i have to import a scanner so i did that as you can see from my code. I also tried some code where you can have the user import a string but you can see a bit later in my program i change the variable userChoice into a number. So basically i just need help with this. If there is some way to have a variable type that can store both numbers or strings that would be best. But im tottaly open to other ways of doing this! Thanks in advanced! Here is the code:

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hi");
        int bob;
        bob = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
        System.out.println(bob);


          System.out.println("Enter heads or tails?");
          System.out.println("You entered "+ userChoice);

          if (bob == 0) {
            System.out.println("Computer flipped heads"); 
          }

          else {
              System.out.println("Computer flipped tails");
          }



          if(userChoice == "Heads") {
              userChoice = 0;

          }

          else {
              userChoice = 1;
          }



          if (userChoice == bob) {
              System.out.println("You win!");
          }


          else {
              System.out.println("Sorry you lost!")

          }


          }

    }
```

Comment: Oh yes btw, you can see that i refer to userChoice often, thats the variable name i want for whatever stores the user import!

Comment: By import, do you mean entered text?  That's usually called "input", "import" is a very different thing?

Comment: Oh ok ya sorry thats what i meant, im not a very good programmer yet xD. Sometimes my terminoligy is a bit off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a scanner, as you said:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then, prompt the user to enter something in:

```
String userChoice = in.nextLine();
```

Also, when you compared strings:

```
if(userChoice == "Heads") {...
```

that's bad to do for none-primitive objects. It's best to only use the `==` to compare values that are `int`s or `enum`s. If you compare a String like this, it won't work, because it's checking if the objects are the same. Instead, compare like this:

```
if(userChoice.equals("Heads")) {...
```

Also, to convert to an int (NOTE: You can't convert one type of object to another that aren't related in any way! You'll have to create a new object if you're wanting to do that), do this:

```
int myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString); // NOTE: Can throw NumberFormatException if non-number character is found.
```

So your program should look somewhat like:

```
    package test;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class testclass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //System.out.println("hi");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int bob;
            int userChoice;
            String input;
            bob = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            System.out.println(bob);

            System.out.println("Enter heads or tails?");
            input = in.nextLine(); // waits for user to press enter.
            System.out.println("You entered "+ input);

            if (bob == 0) {
                System.out.println("Computer flipped heads"); 
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Computer flipped tails");
            }

            if(input.equals("Heads")) {
                userChoice = 0;
            }
            else {
                userChoice = 1;
            }

            if (userChoice == bob) {
                System.out.println("You win!");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Sorry you lost!");
            }

            in.close(); // IMPORTANT to prevent memory leaks
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I really appreciate how detailed this explanation is and the thoroughness of the answer! Thanks so much for spending the time to write this! Heleped alot!

Answer (score 0):

You've already imported the Scanner class so you can now create a variable of the type Scanner for taking inputs.

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner();
 userChoice = in.nextLine();
```

`nextLine()` can be used to input a character or a string from the user.

To convert the string into a integer, You can assign the integer value to the string in the following way.

```
   if(userChoice == "Heads") {
             userChoice = "" + 0;
          }
      else {
             userChoice = "" + 1;
      }
```

Comment: The other part was converting it to an `int` (that's at least what I can tell from the question so far; it's kind of hard to read)

Comment: @Pokechu22 The string can be converted to integer easily

Comment: Yea, but it seems like OP doesn't know how to so it would be best to include that.

Comment: Thanks! Good way to convert strings into intergers!

Answer (score 0):

Having imported java.util.Scanner, to get input from the user as a String, create a Scanner object that parameterizes System.in and assign userChoice the value of nextLine() invoked by the Scanner object:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String userChoice = input.nextLine();
```

A few things about your code. The relational operator, `==`, is used for comparing primitive data - not objects. Use `string1.equals(string2)` to see if two strings are equal.
Also, `bob = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*2);` is really  `bob = (int)(Math.random() * 2);`
because casting a double as an integer truncates the double to the highest integer less than or equal to it.

Comment: Cool ok thank you! Also thanks for that little tip about the Math.random thing. Sorry about that im used to javascript so ya!

Comment: No problem at all, Ashwin. Good luck on your journey of learning java. A bit tricky/clumsy at first but gets easier Lol.

Answer (score 0):

"String" datatype in Java can hold both numbers and strings (as you asked). You can get user input using Scanner utility as below:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner();
userChoice = input.nextLine(); // if it is a string 
//userChoice = input.nextInt(); // if it's integer choice
```

If your string is an integer then you can also parse it to get its integer value. For parsing:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(userChoice);
```

Also for comparing String values you should use "equals" function rather than "==".

```
if(userChoice.equals("Heads")){...} //rather than if(userChoice == "Heads"){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to get the ideas.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rd = new Random();
    //Enter 1 0R 0
    int bob = rd.nextInt(2);
    String userChoice;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    userChoice = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered " + userChoice + " and bob is " + bob);
    int uc = Integer.parseInt(userChoice);
    if (uc == bob) {
        System.out.println("Hehe");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry");
    }
}
```